# How can i position a dropdown at cursor position inside a textarea?

Tags: css, css-float

How can i position my dropdown at cursor position inside a textarea? I have found this question was already asked here many times but i cant able figure out the correct solution ..

this is the [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/uyufiw/12/edit)

please help me with your suggestions

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't think of any way to do it in a textbox, because you can't insert an element in a textbox. What might be possible is using a div with `contentEditable="true"` and somehow format it to look like a textbox. You can determine the offset with selectionStart, then replace `abcd[cursor]efgh` with `abcd<div>yourdiv</div>efgh`. As it is not really an answer to your question, I'll leave it as a comment.

Comment: yeah i tried with contenteditable div but got struck up in inserting another div at the cursor position . I'm trying to insert a div when i type '@' at the cursor position and didn't find a way to go... Using .append() will not insert the div at the cursor postion when i type '@' anywhere in the middle http://jsbin.com/uyufiw/25/edit

Comment: `$('#target').selectionStart` or something like that can be used to find the offset of the cursor, which you can use to create two substrings. One from the beginning to the cursor, and one from the cursor to the end. You can then replace the contents of `$('#target')` with `firststring + yourdiv + laststring`. To insert something, you can replace the `<ul></ul>` with the option that is chosen. (This is just semi-syntax, but something like `this.parent.outerHTML = this.value` on an li-element.)

Also sorry, but I can't really test on this computer, so can't do much but giving cryptic clues.

Answer (score 4):

I know it isn't an exact answer on the question (this solution doesn't use a textarea, but a contentEditable div), but I don't think there is any way of getting x-y-coordinates using either the event, an attribute or function on the textarea or an attribute or function on the Selection object.

I have meshed up an example [on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/omoruy/4). Please note that I haven't bothered testing for compatibility in other browsers and that it won't return the caret to where you left off. I can't figure out the code for that. I believe `window.getSelection()` will not work in IE, and in IE8- it would be completely different. You probably want to make sure too, that the menu will not be displayed right from the edge of the screen.

---

**The HTML**

```
<div id="target" contentEditable="true">Type @ to see the dropdown.... </div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-menu hide" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li><a>One</a> </li>
    <li><a>Two</a></li>
    <li><a>Three</a></li>
    <li><a>Four</a> </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
#target {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#dummy {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

**The Javascript & JQuery**

```
$("#target").keydown( function(e) {

  if(e.which === 50 && e.shiftKey === true ) {
    //Prevent this event from actually typing the @
    e.preventDefault();

    //console.log( window.getSelection() );
    var sel = window.getSelection();

    var offset = sel.baseOffset;
    var node = sel.focusNode.parentNode;

    //Get the text before and after the caret
    var firsttext = node.innerHTML.substr(0,sel.baseOffset);
    var nexttext = (sel.baseOffset != sel.focusNode.length ) ? node.innerHTML.substr( sel.baseOffset, sel.focusNode.length) : "";

    //Add in @ + dummy, because @ is not in there yet on keydown
    node.innerHTML = firsttext + '@<div id="dummy"></div>' + nexttext;

    //Transfer all relevant data to the dropdown menu

    $('.dropdown').css('left', $('#dummy')[0].offsetLeft).css('top', $('#dummy')[0].offsetTop).prop('x-custom-offset', offset + 1);

    //Delete the dummy to keep it clean
    //This will split the contents into two text nodes, which we don't want
    //$('#dummy').remove(); 
    node.innerHTML = firsttext + '@' + nexttext;

    //Put the caret back in place where we left off
    //...I can't seem to figure out how to correctly set the range correctly...

    $('#dropdown').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');    
  } else {
    $('#dropdown').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    $('.dropdown').removeProp('x-custom-offset');
  }
});

$('#dropdown').on( 'click', 'li a', function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('#target').html( function( i, oldtext ) {
    var firsttext = oldtext.substr( 0, $('.dropdown').prop('x-custom-offset') );
    var nexttext = oldtext.substr( $('.dropdown').prop('x-custom-offset'), oldtext.length );

    console.log( e );

    var inserttext = e.target.innerText;

    //Cleanup
    $('#dropdown').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');

    return firsttext + inserttext + nexttext;
  } );
} );
```

---

**The explanation**

This example works based on that you can insert an element in a contentEditable and retrieve it's offset to the top and the left of the screen. When shift + key 50 is pressed, the event handler will prevent the @ from being written and instead inserts the @ + dummy object itself. Then we retrieve the offset from this object and move the dropdown menu to that offset. Furthermore, we save the character-offset as a custom property `x-custom-offset` of the menu, so that we can insert a value at that specific location. We then need to remove the dummy div, but if we would remove the dummy with `$('#dummy').remove()` the text node before the dummy and the text node behind the dummy will not merge. This will delete the last textnode if we were to put an other @ somewhere and/or place it in the wrong location. Therefore, we simply replace the contents of the editable div again. Last, the caret must be set back to it's original position. I cannot figure out how to do this properly though.

The second handler is to insert text into the textbox. The code should be self-explanatory. The `x-custom-offset` property we set earlier is used here to insert the text into the correct place in the textbox. `$('#dropdown').on( 'click', 'li a', function( e ) { ... } );` will attach the click event to the `ul` instead of the `li`'s, so that it will keep working if you dynamically create the `li`'s (but it will only fire if you click the link part).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position of the mouse and then move the drop-down list to this position.
You just need to ensure the popup content has a higher z-index than the element you'd like it occlude, and that it's position is set to absolute.

Here's a small test sample I wrote once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt);}
function toggleClass(element, newStr)
{
    index=element.className.indexOf(newStr);
    if ( index == -1)
        element.className += ' '+newStr;
    else
    {
        if (index != 0)
            newStr = ' '+newStr;
        element.className = element.className.replace(newStr, '');
    }
}
function forEachNode(nodeList, func)
{
    var i, n = nodeList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

function mInit()
{
}

function onShowBtn(e)
{
    var element = byId('popup');
    element.className = element.className.replace(' hidden', '');
    var str = '';//'border-radius: 32px; border: solid 5px;';
    e = e||event;
    str += "left: " + e.pageX + "px; top:"+e.pageY+"px;"
    element.setAttribute('style',str);
}
function onHideBtn()
{
    var element = byId('popup');
    if (element.className.indexOf(' hidden') == -1)
        element.className += ' hidden';
}

</script>
<style>
#controls
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid 1px #555;
    background: #AAA;
}
#popup
{
    border: solid 1px #777;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 12px;
    background: #DDD;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
}
#popup.hidden
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='controls'>
        <input type='button' value='show' onclick='onShowBtn()'>
        <input type='button' value='hide' onclick='onHideBtn()'>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id='popup'>
        <p>This is some assorted
            text</p>
            <hr>
        <ul>
            <li>item a</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>item iii</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How I read it, OP is asking how to display something on the position of the cursor (that thing that displays where in a textbox you are typing) -or in other words- how to obtain the coordinates of the cursor, *not* where the mouse is when the user presses a key and *not* how to display something on those coordinates. e.pageX does not exist for the keyDown event.

Comment: Indeed. I've just re-read it. It seems so clear now. That is a rather different question to the one I wrongly answered. Thank-you. :)